# How do I validate an email address using a regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have the following email validation regex in JavaScript. It doesn't actually return anything, but I think it should (true or false).

What's wrong with this code?

```
function isEmail(aa){
    var testx=/^([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22))*\x40([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d))*$/
    return testx.test(aa);
}

<input type="text" name="email" id="email" onChange="isEmail(this.value)">
```

Comment: `return testx.test(aa)` <- variable not string

Comment: Do you think you'll maintain this regex ? You should read [this](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/).

Comment: `onchange="return isEmail(this.value)"` - except I don't think you can cancel an onchange event. What do you expect to actually happen if the entered value fails the validation?

Comment: @Ghozt I think it'd be helpful for everyone if you broke the regex out into mulitple lines and tell us what you think each line should do, instead of dumping a regex that's hard to follow on others.

Comment: +1 @dystroy, nice article ! :)

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) for more regex suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're testing for string `'aa'`, change

```
return testx.test('aa');
```

to

```
return testx.test(aa);
```

See: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RP4dx/)

Comment: I just saw that and edited it, it didnt help at all. The browser still does not return anything.

Comment: @Ghozt well, besides that it seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

Email validation via regular expressions seems to be extremely complicated.

- [How to Find or Validate an Email Address](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)
- [regexp-based address validation](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)
- [I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx)

If possible you should use HTML5 form validation

`<input type="email">`

[diveintohtml5.info](http://diveintohtml5.info) is a good place to learn more about [form validation](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#validation).

As far as I know the validation is a browser side thing that only works togehter with sumbit buttons. There is no javascript api for checking if a specific string is valid.